# Easily usable and free video editing software?

Tags: video

We are searching for a Video Editing software, that is:

- free / without placing watermark on the output
- can cut videos / append them
- can remove sound from the video
- can put text on the video
- can speed up the video
- can be used by a non-IT person! (so like few clicks to do the job..)

Platform could be anything, ex.: Android, Windows, Linux, etc.

We currently found an Android application which can do this (few clicks really), but it puts a watermark on the output video.

This is my first try on Software Recommendations, so please, say if I forgot something.

Comment: https://windowsreport.com/windows-movie-maker-windows-10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out **VSDC Free Video Editor** http://www.videosoftdev.com/free-video-editor/download

It's a free video editing program for Windows. It is quite complex given a lot of functionalities it has, but I think it is not too complex.

Comment: VSDC Free Video Editor looks very promising, we have found zero issues so far, and the non IT person learnt the bigger steps in 30 mins :) THANK YOU!